# C# LDAP Query to Get Managers of users in certain groups

Tags: c#, ldap

I have currently written a c# script to retrieve users that belong to three separate user groups - it looks like this...

```
string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=org";
DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath); 
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|(memberof=CN=group1,OU=Groups,OU=<ou>,DC=dc,DC=<dc>,DC=org)(memberof=CN=group2,OU=Groups,OU=<ou>,DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=org)(memberof=CN=group3,OU=Groups,OU=<ou>,DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=org)))";
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samaccountname");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("usergroup");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayname");
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("manager");
SearchResult result;
SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();
```

Using this code, I am able to retrieve any properties exposed for this user, including the "manager" record. The manager record is exposed as a DN at this level:

```
Manager = "CN=MTK93,OU=Users,OU=<ou>,DC=<dc>,DC=<dc>,DC=org"
```

What is really want is to be able to recursively get all of the user attributes for each manager of the folks returned by the existing query - and then combine them into one dataset...

For example, consider the following hierarchy....

```
Lisa (manager's manager)
   | 
   | -- Tim (Manager)
   |    mail = tim@a.com, usergroup = groupA, manager = Lisa
   |     | 
   |     |-- Mike
   |     |    mail = mike@a.com, usergroup = group1, manager = Tim
   |     |-- Lori
   |     |    mail = lori@a.com, usergroup = group2, manager = Tim
   | -- Katie (another manager)
         |    mail = katie@a.com, usergroup = groupB, manager = Lisa
         |
         |-- John
         |    mail = john@a.com, usergroup = group3, manager = Katie
         |-- Larry
              mail = larry@a.com, usergroup = group4, manager = Katie
```

My query is returning mike, lori, katie, and john because they exist in the groups I am querying for (group1, group2, group3) - but I need Tim and Katie's user record too (because they are managers of someone that belongs to those groups)

The ideal output would look something like this...

```
Name       Mail        Group        Manager
------------------------------------------------
Mike     mike@a.com   group1        Tim's DN
Lori     lori@a.com   group2        Tim's DN
John     john@a.com   group3        Katie's DN
Katie    katie@a.com  groupB        Lisa's DN
Tim      time@a.com   groupA        Lisa's DN
```

Note: I do not want Lisa (nobody in the level below her belongs to group1, group2, or group3) or Larry (doesn't belong to group1, group2, or group3)

The recursive nature of this LDAP query is proving to be pretty tough to figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the results I needed by taking the following approach:

1. Dynamically build a LDAP query using the groups
2. Load the users from group 1, 2, and 3 into a list using a custom function
3. Use Linq to get a distinct list of managers from the resulting list of users in groups 1, 2, and 3
4. Dynamically build another LDAP query using the distinguished names of the managers
5. Load the manager records into another list and combine with the original list of users
6. Remove any duplicates

   ```
   // class variable
   List<ActiveDirectoryUser> recordsToInsert;

   // build the query appender
   string queryAppender = "";
   foreach (string activeDirectoryGroup in activeDirectoryGroups)
   {
       queryAppender += "(memberof=CN=" + activeDirectoryGroup + ",OU=Groups,OU=<<ou>>,DC=<<dc>>,DC=<<dc>>,DC=<org>>)";
   }

   // create the ldap query string
   var ldapQueryForUsersInDtGroups = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|" + queryAppender + "))";

   // first get the users that belong to the active directory groups...
   recordsToInsert = getEmployeeRecordsFromLdapQuery(ldapQueryForUsersInDtGroups);

   // then, query again to make sure we are including the managers for the people returned from the first query
   var distinctManagers = (from record in recordsToInsert select record.manager).Distinct();

   // build an ldap query to get only the records for the managers we need
   // example query string with 2 managers: 
   // (&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)

   queryAppender = "";
   foreach (var manager in distinctManagers)
   {
       queryAppender += "(distinguishedName=" + manager + ")";
   }

   // ldap query filter for the managers
   var ldapQueryForManagers = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(|" + queryAppender + "))";

   // combine the result set with the managers result set
   recordsToInsert.AddRange(getEmployeeRecordsFromLdapQuery(ldapQueryForManagers));

   // filter off any duplicates.
   uniqueRecordsToInsert = recordsToInsert.GroupBy(x => x.employeeId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList<ActiveDirectoryUser>();
   ```